# 2005 Ford Taurus Cruise Control and Horn Not Working

Tags: ford, troubleshooting, taurus, cruise-control, horn

I have already checked the most obvious things I believe. The fuses are all good and the horn relay clicks when I press the horn. The cruise control servo spins freely by hand. The cruise control deactivation switch has been replaced along with the clock spring. I checked all the connections in the steering wheel itself and everything looks fine.

However, the horn and cruise control still do not work. The cruise control light will come on when you turn it on, but it will not set the acceleration when you push the button. The airbag light does not come on.

I believe that the horn and cruise control not working are related and the only thing I can think of is a possible corroded ground wire connection somewhere. These things had stopped working before and replacing the clockspring was the solution. However, that does not seem to be the problem now because the signal is definitely getting to the horn relay at least.

My question is, did I miss anything that could be the problem and in the case that it is most likely a broken wire problem, how would I go about diagnosing it?

Comment: Does the horn sound if you give it a direct feed?

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure where the horn is located :P but the horn and cruise control stopped working at the same time and the clockspring fixed both initially and now they both don't work again (and I'm assuming its related) and its not a clockspring issue because the horn relay clicks.

Comment: terminal 87 on the horn relay is the output to horn. check it with a multimeter the horn relay will pass either ground or power depending on the setup.